# Simplify & condense multiple editorial operations on an array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, output

I have some raw output that I want to clean up and make presentable but right now I go about it in a very ugly and cumbersome way, I wonder if anyone might know a clean and elegant way in which to perform the same operation.

```
    int size = charOutput.size();
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 1; i--) 
    {
        if(charOutput.get(i).compareTo(charOutput.get(i - 1)) == 0) 
        {
            charOutput.remove(i);
        }
    }


    for(int x = 0; x < charOutput.size(); x++)
    {
        if(charOutput.get(x) == '?') 
        {
            charOutput.remove(x);
        }
    }


    String firstOne = Arrays.toString(charOutput.toArray());

    String secondOne = firstOne.replaceAll(",","");

    String thirdOne = secondOne.substring(1, secondOne.length() - 1);

    String output = thirdOne.replaceAll(" ","");


    return output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZouZou has the right code for fixing the final few calls in your code. I have some suggestions for the `for` loops. I hope I got them right...

These work after you get the `String` represented by `charOutput`, using a method such as the one suggested by ZouZou.

Your first block appears to remove all repeated letters. You can use a regular expression for that:

```
Pattern removeRepeats = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{1,}");
// "(.)" creates a group that matches any character and puts it into a group
// "\\1" gets converted to "\1" which is a reference to the first group, i.e. the character that "(.)" matched
// "{1,}" means "one or more"
// So the overall effect is "one or more of a single character"
```

To use:

```
removeRepeats.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1");
// This creates a Matcher that matches the regex represented by removeRepeats to the contents of s, and replaces the parts of s that match the regex represented by removeRepeats with "$1", which is a reference to the first group captured (i.e. "(.)", which is the first character matched"
```

To remove the question mark, just do

```
Pattern removeQuestionMarks = Pattern.compile("\\?");
// Because "?" is a special symbol in regex, you have to escape it with a backslash
// But since backslashes are also a special symbol, you have to escape the backslash too.
```

And then to use, do the same thing as was done above except with `replaceAll("");`

And you're done!

If you really wanted to, you can combine a lot of regex into two super-regex expressions (and one normal regex expression):

```
Pattern p0 = Pattern.compile("(\\[|\\]|\\,| )"); // removes brackets, commas, and spaces
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{1,}"); // Removes duplicate characters
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\?");

String removeArrayCharacters = p0.matcher(charOutput.toString()).replaceAll("");
String removeDuplicates = p1.matcher(removeArrayCharacters).replaceAll("$1");
return p2.matcher(removeDuplicates).replaceAll("");
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice job on yours too; I didn't quite get the gist of what the poster was trying to do at first and didn't realize it until you answered.

Comment: in place of compile, should I replace that with charOutput?

Comment: hmm, please forgive me for not being more lucid in my original post

Comment: No, the `Pattern.compile()` calls should stay exactly as they are. `Pattern.compile()` takes in a regex `String` and turns it into a `Pattern` object, which then can be used to perform various operation on `CharSequence` objects such as `Strings`. In my example code the `compile()` calls are used so that you can do various things **after** you get a `String` from `charOutput`.

Comment: I think this is cool as hell and I want to use it but when I tried to add it into my code it generated an error, I think i'm not quite understanding how to use it

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what the error is!

Comment: ah, sorry for being daft. the error is that it leaves the question marks in.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. It's my mistake; there should be no space between the final "|" and "\\?" ("(\\[|\\]|\\,| | \\?)" should be "(\\[|\\]|\\,| |\\?)")

Comment: that now removes question marks but it also is removing all duplicates, though sometimes there can be duplicates permitted, so long as they're seperated by a question mark

Comment: All right, take a look at my updated solution. Sorry for missing that the first time around. Basically I moved the part where I removed the question mark to another `Pattern` that is applied after duplicates are removed.

Comment: man please don't apologize, that was really amazing and beautiful what you've done, I didn't even know that such things were possible. do you  know some good resource where I can find some information on how to use these kind of regex expressions?

Comment: The online API for Java's [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides a good reference as to what symbols are accepted in Java and what they stand for. Oracle also has a [set of lessons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) that could be useful. [This website](http://regexpal.com/) is a good place to test the regexes you come up with. Google can show you many more, but in my experience those resources as well as other StackOverflow answers and the testing I do myself are usually sufficient.

Comment: Regexes are incredibly powerful if used right. I hope you find good use for them in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder` and append each character you want, at the end just return `myBuilder.toString();`

Instead of this:

```
String firstOne = Arrays.toString(charOutput.toArray());
String secondOne = firstOne.replaceAll(",","");
String thirdOne = secondOne.substring(1, secondOne.length() - 1);
String output = thirdOne.replaceAll(" ","");
return output;
```

Simply do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Character c : charOutput){
    sb.append(c);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Note that you are doing a lot of unnecessary work (by iterating through the list and removing some elements). What you can actually do is just iterate one time and then if the condition fullfits your requirements (the two adjacent characters are not the same and no question mark) then append it to the `StringBuilder` directly.

This task could also be a job for a regular expression.

Comment: yeah but i need to clean it up first

Comment: @user3580294 He's getting the String representation of the char array, removing `','`, `'['`, `']'` and spaces.

Comment: That isn't what your code does, though... You're doing the equivalent of `return firstOne;`

Comment: @user3580294 You are right, I made a mistake, I don't know why I assumed `toArray()` returned a `char[]` array. `new String(charOutput.toArray());` won't even compile anyway :)

Comment: Oh wait.... I'm an idiot. My apologies. I was talking about something else (mistakenly), but glad to know that I helped catch something else

Comment: Hmmm... Could you possibly use the `toArray(T[] array)` method in `ArrayList` to make the `String` using its constructor?

Comment: @user3580294 No unfortunately there is no constructor that accepts a `Character` array.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that Java's autoboxing mechanism would take care of that... Guess that doesn't work.

Comment: @ZouZou Wow, that's really fantastic! so... essential! :)

Comment: @matthias.anglicus You should also consider the regex answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Regex try this version to remove consecutive characters and '?':

```
int size = charOutput.size();
if (size == 1) return Character.toString((Character)charOutput.get(0));
else if (size == 0) return null;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    Character temp = (Character)charOutput.get(i);
    if (!temp.equals(charOutput.get(i+1)) && !temp.equals('?'))
        sb.append(temp);
}

//for the last element
if (!charOutput.get(size-1).equals(charOutput.get(size-2)) 
        && !charOutput.get(size-1).equals('?'))
    sb.append(charOutput.get(size-1));

return sb.toString();
```

Comment: please forgive my ignorance, but what is Regex?